# OpenSSL error 20: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: ssl, centos5, openssl

I'm trying to get a Network Solutions SSL to work and I'm not having much luck.

openssl verify gives me error 20 unable to get local issuer certificate

I've followed the directions [here](http://www.networksolutions.com/support/installation-of-an-ev-ssl-certificate-on-apache-mod-ssl-openssl/) and [here](http://www.networksolutions.com/support/csr-for-apache-with-mod-ssl-openssl/) and copied the crt file and the Apache_Plesk_Install.txt file to the certs directory and I put the private key in the private directory.  I've verified in openssl.cnf that I put the files in the proper directories.

I followed Nick Burch's guide to installing CA Certificates and have had no luck in resolving the issue.

If anyone can give me any ideas of what's going on, I would definitely appreciate it.

Platform
CentOS 5.7
OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5

Comment: Nick Burch's guide can be found [here](http://gagravarr.org/writing/openssl-certs/others.shtml#ca-openssl).

Comment: Is Apache presenting the full certificate chain (`openssl s_client -showcerts`)?  Does it work when you specify the trusted CA cert directly on the OpenSSL command line?

Comment: The only cert openssl s_client -showcerts shows me is a self signed certificate.

Comment: When I run openssl verify on the CA cert, it doesn't output anything.  The process seems to hang.

Comment: Check if it's a valid file?  `openssl x509 -in /path/to/cert -noout -text`

Comment: openssl x509 comes back with CA information for Network Solutions valid until May 30, 2020

Comment: Oh - your `openssl verify` command was probably just waiting for input.  What was the exact command that you ran?

Comment: I figured out why the process hung on openssl verify of the trusted CA cert.  I needed to add the CA root cert to that directory.  I'm still getting error 20 for the server SSL, though.

Comment: New info.  When I run openssl verify -CApath /path/to/CA /path/to/cert my server certificate comes back ok.  When I run openssl verify /path/to/cert I get error 20.  That seems to indicate that openssl isn't using the CA path that I think it's using.  I'm going to double check my openssl.cnf file.

Comment: Well, OpenSSL's trust really doesn't matter for getting the certificate working in Apache.  What issues are you having with that (since the certs look perfectly valid)?

Comment: The domain keeps presenting a self-signed certificate that is assigned to localhost.localdomain instead of using the SSL I got from Network Solutions for my actual domain.

Comment: What does your Apache config for the site look like?  And did you fully restart (not just reload) Apache after making the configuration changes?

Comment: I did a full stop/start on Apache.  Config options for SSL for the domain are as follows: SSLEngine on, SSLCertificateFile /absolute/path/to/cert, SSLCertificateKeyFile /absolute/path/to/key, SSLCertificateChainFile /absolute/path/to/file, SSLCACertificateFile /absolute/path/to/CA

Comment: Is there another SSL virtualhost in place elsewhere, perhaps?  What's the output from `apache2ctl -S`?

Comment: There is only one SSL virtual host in place right now.  I did notice something strange in the output, though.  My unsecured domains (port 80) all use the domain name as the default server.  My secured domain uses the local FQDN as the default server.  It seems to be using the default settings from the ssl.conf file for Apache instead of the settings I designated in the VirtualHost section of httpd.conf.

Comment: What's in ssl.conf?

Comment: ssl.conf has a _default_:443 entry with SSLCertificateFile /path/to/self-signed/cert and SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/self-signed/key.  I haven't been able to figure out how to override those settings, though.  Shouldn't the directives within httpd.conf have done that?

Comment: Ok.  I moved the SSL directives from httpd.conf into a VirtualHost inside the ssl.conf file ahead of the _default_:443 VirtualHost and that seems to have cleared up the SSL issue.  Shane, you have been an incredible help and I thank you greatly for taking this much time out of your day to assist me.

Comment: Great!  When the system allows you to, go ahead and put in an answer to the question and mark it as accepted, so that future searchers with the same issue can find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my ssl.conf file in Apache.  It was overriding the VirtualHost settings for the domain in httpd.conf, so I moved my VirtualHost settings into ssl.conf ahead of the *default*:443 VirtualHost entry.  Doing this resolved my issue.

Thanks again to Shane Madden for all of the help on this issue.